Spectral Theorem applied to Laplace-Beltrami Operator
Consider $(M,g)$ a compact Riemannian manifold, and $L^2(M)$ the Hilbert space of the square-integrable functions with respect to the Riemannian volume form. I want to study the eigenvalue problem for the Laplace-Beltrami operator $\Delta_g$, and more generally for a self-adjoint operator acting on $L^2(M)$.
I have tried to use the Hilbert-Schmidt theorem, but I need the operator to be compact (I don't know if $\Delta_g$ is compact). So, I intend to apply a result from functional analysis to state that for the eigenvalue problem $\Delta_g \phi + \lambda \phi = 0$ the set of eigenvalues consists of a sequence $0 \leq \lambda_1 < \lambda_2 <... \rightarrow \infty$ and each associated eigenspace is finite-dimensional. The references I have read assume this result but offer no proof. Any help would be much appreciated.

Do you know that $\Delta_g^{-1}$ is compact?

@SeverinSchraven I didn’t know that. Could you please tell me how can I use that to apply the Hilbert-Schmidt theorem? Thanks

Typically one shows that the resolvent is compact and then gets that the spectrum of the original operator consists of eigenvalues of finite multiplicity and $\lambda_n \rightarrow \infty$.

To get the compactness of the resolvent you can you the Rellich-Kondrachov theorem.

Thanks, @SeverinSchraven. Is there any reference where I can find this procedure?

Typically when we want to prove that a certain operator has a spectrum $0\leq \lambda_1<\lambda_2<\dots$, all eigenvalues have finite multiplicity and $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \lambda_n$ we turn to the resolvent of the (shifted) operator and show that that operator is compact.
Let's assume that you already know that $-\Delta_g$ is self-adjoint. Then one can use the fact that $\langle -\Delta_g u, u \rangle_{L^2(M)}=\Vert \text{grad}(u) \Vert_{L^2(M)}\geq 0$ to get that $\mathrm{spec}(-\Delta_g)\subseteq [0, \infty)$. In particular we have that $\mathrm{spec}(-\Delta_g+1) \subseteq [1,\infty)$. Thus, by functional calculus, we get that we the inverse of $(-\Delta_g+1)$ exists. If we can prove that $R=(-\Delta_g+1)^{-1}$ is compact then we get from the spectral theorem that all the desired properties of the spectrum of $-\Delta_g$ hold true (for the details see Reed-Simon, Methods of modern Mathematical Physics IV: Analysis of Operators, Theorem XIII.64).
Thus, we are left to prove that $R$ is compact. For this we are going to use a special case of Rellich's theorem (see for example Proposition 3.4 in Partial Differential Equations I by Taylor):

For any compact manifold $M$ any $s\in \mathbb{R}$ and for all $\sigma>0$ we have that the inclusion map
$$ j: H^{s+\sigma}(M) \rightarrow H^s(M) $$
is compact.

Let $f,u\in L^2(M)$ such that $Rf=u$. Then we have $-\Delta_g u+u=f$. Multiply by $\overline{u}$ and use integration by parts to get
$$ \Vert u \Vert_{H^1(M)}^2 = \int_M \overline{u} f \leq \Vert u \Vert_{L^2(M)} \Vert f \Vert_{L^2(M)}. $$
This means that $R$ maps $L^2(M)$ into $H^1(M)$. Thus, $R=j\circ R$ is a compact operator.

Amazing answer, thank you so much!

@ayphyros You are very welcome.
